# my flutter app is not running only in my mobile device

Tags: flutter

my flutter doctor has no issue  [image]

I attach my problem when I run flutter run [image]

My settings.gradle
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xhab.jpg

Comment: The error message tells you there is a problem in settings.gradle. Can you show that file to us?

Comment: I shared my settings.gradle on the question